# Pipenv lock: how to cache downloads for transfer to an offline machine

Tags: python, deployment, continuous-integration, offline, pipenv

I am looking for a way to create a self-contained archive of all dependencies required to satisfy a `Pipfile.lock`. One way to achieve this would be to point `PIPENV_CACHE_DIR` at an empty temporary directory, run `pipenv install`, ship the contents of that directory, and use it on the offline machine.

E.g., this should work:

```sh
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
if [ -n "$offline" ]; then
    tar -xf pipenv_cache.tar -C "$tmpdir"
fi
pipenv --rm
PIPENV_CACHE_DIR="$tmpdir" PIP_CACHE_DIR="$tmpdir" pipenv install
if [ -n "$online" ]; then
    tar -cf pipenv_cache.tar -C "$tmpdir" .
fi
```

However, there are a number of problems with this script, one being that it can’t use the online machine’s cache, having to download everything every time instead.

The question is, is there a better way, that doesn’t involve a custom script? Maybe some documented community best practices?

Ideally, there would exist an interface like:

```sh
pipenv lock --create-archive <file_name>
pipenv install --from-archive <file_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

With some Shell scripting work, [wheelfreeze](https://github.com/amiryal/wheelfreeze) can be made to do it.

To create the archive (in a Bash shell):

```
(. "$(pipenv --venv)"/bin/activate && wheelfreeze <(pipenv lock -r))
```

And to install from the archive:

```
wheelfreeze/install "$(pipenv --venv)"
```

---

**Disclosure:** I created wheelfreeze while trying to solve the problem – “to scratch my own itch”, as the saying goes.